# How to convert number of days into seconds in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am writing a shell script to convert the number of days to the number of seconds.

I'm working on getting the values first in variables and without variables.

Below is the script I am running, but it doesn't work for me.

```
DAYS=4
SECONDSPERDAY=86400
SECONDS=$(expr $DAYS/86400)
echo=$SECONDS
```

Comment: Or i even tried with SECONDS=$(expr $DAYS / $SECONDSPERDAY)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: As i ran the file, it didnt show any output, i wonder, is their any syntax error..

Comment: The error is `echo=$SECONDS`. Change to `echo $SECONDS` to get some output

Answer (score 5):

You script works fine, in Bash or Zsh, for example, but `$()` is not compatible with older shells. Maybe you have a different shell?

Also, `echo=blah` probably isn't what you want, and obviously you have the formula wrong.

Try this:

```
DAYS=4
SECONDSPERDAY=86400
seconds=`expr $DAYS '*' $SECONDSPERDAY`
echo $seconds
```

If you *aren't* using an old non-POSIX-compliant shell, then the better way to do it might be like this:

```
DAYS=4
SECONDSPERDAY=86400
seconds=$(( DAYS * SECONDSPERDAY ))
echo $seconds
```

---

Edit...

**WARNING: `$SECONDS` has a special meaning in Bash!**

The value of `$SECONDS` automatically increases as time passes. You can reset it by assigning a value, but it won't remain set to that value. The above script will work fine, *probably*, because it will execute very quickly, but any subsequent use of the value may get a different value. I've edited my answer to use `$seconds` to avoid the conflict.

Comment: I dont understand the operator \*  , i want to divide days by secondsperday..when i checked for which shell i am using- ps $$, it showed bash

Comment: `4 / 86400 = 0` but `4 * 86400 = 345600`. Which do you prefer?

Comment: [`$(( ... ))` is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04), so it is the better way in any standard-compliant shell.

Comment: @muru Thanks, apparently it is in POSIX *now*. Has it always been so? Anyway, the point is that it's not universally supported. Answer edited.

Comment: @ams I linked to the 2001 edition for that reason - it's been standard for 15 years now. If you're into *universal* support, the given command is not exactly csh either. :)

Comment: While such a calculation is correct in most cases, in general the assumption that 1 day = 86400 seconds is not correct. Some exceptions:
- in many time zones some days have 23 or 25 hours (82800s or 90000s) because of the daylight saving time shift (DST),
- in UTC and time zones related to it some days have 86401 seconds because of added leap seconds.

Comment: @pkalinow, plus the occasional leap second.

Comment: @koolomi, in general, don't use ALLCAPSVARIABLENAMES. Leave those for the shell. I've also seen people get into trouble because they used PATH.